# Laravel 5.2 not found exception for css and js files

Tags: php, laravel

I have set up a laravel 5.2 project on a vps which uses cpanel.

I've configured the subdomain to point to the public folder within the subdomain folder and the app loads as expected.

However my login page is unable to load any assets - it comes up with an `not found http exception` for any of the assets.

for example: `http://subdomain.domain.co.uk/css/app.css`.

Once I log in the assets load correctly in all other pages - just not the log in one. If I then log out and log in again then the assets all load correctly.

Just not sure what's stopping the assets loading and for laravel to try and treat a path to a css file as a route.

Any help appreciated

**Additional Information:**

Here's the mark up for including the css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
```

I've also tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('css/app.css') !!}">
```

This is identical to the pages that load the assets once logged in.

**Folder Structure**

Root/ (a few folders for brevity)

```
subdomain
    app/
        http/
            routes.php
    public/
        css/
            app.css
        js/
            app.js
    vendor
```

The server points to `subdomain\public' as normal laravel setup

It's still happening each time the cache is cleared and only corrects once logged in and only affects the login page

Comment: Does your login view extend the same master layout?

Comment: No - it's a standalone page with no layout but it does use some of the sites resources such as a common css file and jquery files etc

Comment: Could you paste how they are included and for a comparison the same from a working page?

Comment: try `php artisan view:clear` , `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: hi - tried the artisan commands and none made a difference. I still get `NotFoundHttpException` for the page for all the assets

Answer (score 0):

I am noticing that on L5.2 in the public directory it does not include a CSS folder.

Here is the repo's folder for reference: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.2/public

This leads me to believe the assets need to be initially compiled via a `gulp` command which will run [Laravel's Elixer](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/gulpfile.js) and generate the assets.

From the projects root folder run

`gulp` or `sudo gulp`

Take note, if you have not pulled in the assets you will have to run

`npm install` or `sudo npm install` first. Here is the out the box NPM packages pulled for reference: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/package.json.

And if you cannot install using `npm` you will need to install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) first.

Comment: Nope, that's not an issue - the css folder and all the assets exist within the public folder. The assets were compiled with elixir as part of my build but that's not the cause of this problem. The path to the asset is being treated as a route creating the error - but once logged in and reloading the page the assets load correctly.

Comment: Does this happen to have a public repo by chance?

Comment: Hi - it depends on what you mean by a public repo. At the moment the sub domain points to the public folder. I'll add the folder structure to the question for clarity. All the assets are contained within the domain and not hosted elsewhere